# Can I recover my Xbox 360 GTA 5 progress after deleting my profile?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I deleted my profile accidentally and GTA 5 started from 0% while I was at 40% but the progress of the game is shown in the storage. If any one has any idea how I can get back to were I was I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've activated cloud storage and didn't delete it from there there is no way to get it back.